# Why is '@' a security risk in url?

Tags: email, phishing

I'm making a Phishing Filter with Machine Learning and I'm using the features mentioned in this paper http://scialert.net/abstract/?doi=jas.2011.3301.3307

One of the features says "URL contains hexadecimal characters or @ symbol", why is an @ in URL a potencial security risk, and more especific with Phishing?

EDIT: The filter is in the email level, so the URL would be as part of the message

Answer (score 17):

The [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) is composed like so:

```
scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]
```

As you can see, the `@` is used to include (in this case, HTTP) authentication directly in the url.  The question then becomes "Why would a url that includes authentication be a sign of phishing?".

I don't know the author's reasoning, but the most common argument [I've seen](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123150#c10) is that it's an easy way to confuse the user about what the domain is.  For example, `http://www.mozilla.org&login3:141592653589793238462643383279‌​502884197169@example‌​.com/evil` looks very much like it's loading `www.mozilla.org`, but if you look close enough it's actually `example.com/evil`.  Tricking the user into trusting a false website is the core of a phishing attack, so this provides a really nice attack opportunity for a phisher.

Comment: That example you're giving would resolve to `www.google.com` as expected. You can't have an unencoded `/` in the authentication part of the scheme.

Comment: so the URL must look like this? https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%2Fsomethingverylong:somethingevenlonger@malicioussite.com

Comment: Firefox shows an alert windows when visiting such a link and [documented this feature](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.phishy-userpass-length). They illustrate it with the URL `http://www.mozilla.org&login3:141592653589793238462643383279502884197169@example.com/evil` which is designed to trick users into thinking they are visiting `www.mozilla.org` while they are actually on `example.com`.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf Thanks, I've updated my answer (SE only allows me to `@mention` one user at a time).